# Create Dynamic Table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm faced with a very simple task but for some reason the solution is eluding me, probably because my PHP is not good.

I have a table that has 1 header which spans across 4 columns.  In the first column it would be static data, (i.e. headers so to speak but only in the first column).  What I need is to populate the 2nd column and so on based on the results returned.  I'm building a table that when a product is compared it will populate a column with information related to the product

```
<table id="price-compare" class="device-compare" border="1">
<caption>Price</caption>
<?php
$rows = 3;
$cols = 4;

for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){ 
    echo "<tr>";

            for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
            echo "<td>row: ".$tr." column: ".$td."</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>

<tr>
    <td class="left-header"><?php echo $phones->field('name'); ?></td>
    <td><sup>$</sup><?php echo $phones_retail; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="left-header">Fuel Price</td>
    <td><sup>$</sup><?php echo $phones_retail; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="left-header">2-yr Contract Price</td>
    <td style="font-weight: bold; color:#1b75bb;"><sup>$</sup><?php echo $phones_contract; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image: Table Screenshot]

So as you can see, I need the first column to remain unchanged and adding the data related to the product to subsequent columns.

Comment: Could be that i don't get your question right, but you want to do is the first column to be empty? Just put an if clause around your echo in the second loop and check if it's the first column or not. this can't be your problem am i right? D:

Comment: Well not empty, I want first column to be static data, hard coded words if you will and then if I click on a product I want all information associated with it, which I have on the backend, to populate all rows accordingly and then if I click on another phone it will add another column and however many rows is needed to display the data I specify.  For instance, on the Price table, Fuel and 2-year labels will be static, but the phone prices should populate dynamically for the 2 or 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, hope it helps you:

```
  for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
                echo "<td>row: ".$tr." column: ".$td."</td>";
    }

replace the above code by below one:


for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
 if($td == 1)
  {
    echo "<td>Static Data</td>";
  }
 else
 {
    echo "<td>row: ".$tr." column: ".$td."</td>";
 }
 }
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. My code I currently have is here [link](http://pastebin.com/fELtYwfm) and here is the screenshot of what renders, also note that the only reason price is showing is because I have the code outside of the php. [link](http://i.imgur.com/3v1Odzj.png)

Comment: I was able to get it fixed somewhat with this code [link](http://pastebin.com/cwf8yEe5) but as you can see it doesn't loop through the data correctly as far as the static 1st column goes [link](http://i.imgur.com/kjIGoJw.png)